# FreeIPA Forward Zones not working

Tags: internal-dns, freeipa

I have a few replica of FreeIPA 4.6.4 running.  I'm trying to forward request for another DNS domain to their DNS server.   dig/nslookup to the forwarder works, but queries to FreeIPA returns NXDOMAIN

For example, my internal zone is myzone.local.  Through a private network, I'm trying to send all lookups for domain eu.xyz.int. to ip the forwarder at 1.2.3.4.   `dig @1.2.3.4 something.eu.xyz.int` works fine.  On the IPA replica, `dig something.eu.xyz.int` fails.

What am I missing? Should I disable DNSSEC on all FreeIPA replica?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem right now. Check this, maybe you'll find the answer here https://www.freeipa.org/page/Troubleshooting/DNS#Forward_zone_does_not_work